# Add exe file details to binary of compiled Rust code

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

After compiling a Rust command line application to an *.exe binary on Windows I have checked the binary details and they are mostly blank:

[image]

Is there a way to add the `file description`, `file version`, `Product name`, `Product version` via the `Cargo.toml` file to the compiled exe file?

Update:

I have used [winresource](https://github.com/BenjaminRi/winresource) and it worked well according to the instructions of the library.

In `Cargo.toml` I have added a reference to the build script in the `build-dependencies` section:

```
[build-dependencies]
winresource = "0.1.14"
```

And my build.rs script looks like this:

```
extern crate winresource;

fn main() {
    if std::env::var("CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS").unwrap() == "windows" {
        let mut res = winresource::WindowsResource::new();
        res.set_icon("images/aws_client.ico");
        res.compile().unwrap();
    }
}
```

Finally I added a small section to `Cargo.toml` like this one:

```
[package.metadata.winresource]
ProductName = "Command Line AWS Client"
LegalCopyright = "Copyright © 2022"
```

The resulting file properties look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information data of a Windows executable is stored as a resource, in the `.rsrc` section of the program. The rustc compiler will not create such a section, that is the same beahvior of other Windows native compilers: gcc, clang, or MS cl won't do that either.

Instead, you have to write the resource data in a special language (a `*.rc` file) and compile it with a *resource compiler*. That will create an object file that you can link to your program.

Naturally, there is a crate for that! You can try [`winresource`](https://crates.io/crates/winresource) (that has been recently forked from `winres` that seems unmantained).

Or you can compile the resources yourself. There is another crate called [`windres`](https://crates.io/crates/windres) that will find the resource compiler for you. You can add that to your build-dependencies and then write a `build.rs` with something like:

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=build.rs");
    let target_os = std::env::var("CARGO_CFG_TARGET_OS");
    if target_os.as_deref() == Ok("windows") {
        let name = env!("CARGO_PKG_NAME");
        let version = env!("CARGO_PKG_VERSION");
        let mut sv = version.split('.').collect::<Vec<_>>();
        while sv.len() < 4 {
            sv.push("0");
        }
        let file_version = format!("{}, {}, {}, {}", sv[0], sv[1], sv[2], sv[3]);
        windres::Build::new()
            .define("THE_PROJECT", Some(format!(r#""{name}""#).as_str()))
            .define("THE_VERSION", Some(format!(r#""{version}""#).as_str()))
            .define("THE_FILEVERSION", Some(file_version.as_str()))
            .compile("res/resource.rc")?;
        for entry in std::fs::read_dir("res")? {
            let entry = entry?;
            println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed={}", entry.path().display());
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Then, in the `res/resource.rc` file:

```
#pragma code_page(65001)

1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION THE_FILEVERSION
PRODUCTVERSION THE_FILEVERSION
FILEFLAGSMASK 0x0000003Fl //VS_FFI_FILEFLAGSMASK
FILEFLAGS 0x0
FILEOS 0x00040004l //VOS_NT_WINDOWS32
FILETYPE 0x00000001l //VFT_APP
FILESUBTYPE 0x00000000l //VFT2_UNKNOWN
{
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    {
        BLOCK "040904B0"
        {
            VALUE "FileDescription", THE_PROJECT
            VALUE "FileVersion", THE_VERSION
            VALUE "ProductVersion", THE_VERSION
            VALUE "ProductName", THE_PROJECT
        }
    }
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    {
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 0x4B0
    }
}

1 ICON "res/the_icon.ico"
```

A few notes about this file:

- The `#pragma code_page` line declares this file as UTF-8 encoded. There are other code-page values, but UTF-8 is the only right one.
- I'm passing the data from the Cargo.toml to the RC file as C like macros. You can adapt those as you see fit.
- `THE_FILEVERSION` must be exactly 4 comma separated integers. `THE_VERSION` however is a free string. I'm using `build.rs` script to do the conversion.
- Those numeric constants (`0x00000001l`) are equivalent to that constant in the comment. I'm using the constant to avoid having to include the `winver.h` file that causes issues is some environments.
- The values at the root of the file, such as `FILEVERSION` are the *fixed version info*, while the block `StringFileInfo` is has a list of key-value localized strings. There are a lot of [predefined ones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/stringfileinfo-block), and you can even create your own. If you use the localized strings you also need the `VarFileInfo` block declaring the language itself. The integer pair `0x409, 0x4B0` matches the string `"040904B0"`, that means "English, Unicode", I think ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/varfileinfo-block) is a list of codes).
- I've added a line with the EXE icon at the end, because every EXE should have an icon.

You may need a bit of experimentation to get the version you want, but all the pieces are there.